# Wordpress Content Adjusting Itself Based On Content Type

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, themes

I wasn't sure how to search this up but I am looking for a kind of plugin or theme that adjusts homepage content listing similar to the way Facebook timeline adjusts it.

The adjustment is based on the type of content you have (ie, one photo, or three related photos, or a video, or just a regular text/blog).

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You might have more luck on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Crap, I should've posted there. I'm new to the service. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i can understand you if you are looking for this
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-facebook-timeline-mf-timeline/

Creates a visual linear timeline representation from your WordPress posts and other media sources in the style of Facebook Profile Timeline.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It wasn't exactly what I was looking for but seems to be the close enough.